# Removing multiple item from a list for each criteria not being fulfilled

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to build a function that takes a list and removes every item that doesn't meet all the criteria's I've specified.

The structure is the following :

```
def function(my_list):

    for element in my_list:
        if not criteria_1:
            my_list.remove(element)

        else:
            if not criteria_2:
                my_list.remove(element)

    return my_list
```

- The issue is that the list I get as a result contains elements that
  don't match the criteria's
- The expected output is a list that contains only elements that match all the criteria's.

Comment: The problem is that you are iterating and deleting at the same time,

Comment: which means you should append the good elements to a new `list`, or iterate over  the `list` from back to front

Comment: What do you mean ? What would be the correct structure of the function instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can make a one big `if` - it is more readable (i think at least)
- You are deleting and iterating simultaneously which is incorrect - you need to create temporary list

This code should work:

```
def function(my_list):
    tmp = list(my_list)
    
    for element in my_list:
        if not (criteria1 and criteria2 and criteria3):
            tmp.remove(element)

    return tmp
```

Comment: I wouldn't create a copy of the list and then remove data from it. I would create a new list with just the elements I need. Then the whole body of the function boils down to `return [element for element in my_list if criteria1 and criteria2 and criteria3]`.

Comment: Yea you're right. Didn't think of it when I was creating the answer :)